# My div images won't position. Nor place themselves 0px top and left

Tags: html, css, background-image, positioning

Want object to start from 0px top and 0px left and go all the way to the right:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bexpZ.jpg

I showed above. 
This is the html code and css code of it:

```
<div id="page">
                <h1 id="header"></h1>
</div>
-------------------------------------------------------------
body {
    background-image:url(../img/b_webclient_1.png);
    background-position: center center fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

div #header {
    background-image:url(../img/webclient_header.png);
    min-height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    margin:; /* If you want no margin */
    padding:; /*if your want to padding */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Most browsers have a default `body` margin of 8px...
Try adding `margin:0;` to the body above.

Comment: That's the problem it do not help to do so.

Comment: Ah yes, the `h1` tag has a margin as well. Try this: `body,html,h1 {margin:0;padding:0;}`

Comment: Thank you! It worked henryaaron

Answer (score 1):

---

Source: [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) from the World Wide Web consortium

---

`<body>` tags have a default margin of 8 pixels

Reset that by adding this to your CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

---

`<h1>` tags have a default margin of 0.67 em's

Reset that by adding this to your CSS:

```
h1 {
  margin:0;
}
```